# Which wallets support French seed-phrases?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, seed, c++, recover-private-key

I found an old backup seedphrase but it is has French words in it, and I've been struggling to find wallet to restore it as it seems most wallets support only English. There has to be a wallet that supports French bit39 words